# Align image with bottom of frame

Tags: java, swing

So I have an image:

```
ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("foo.png");
JLabel j = new JLabel(i);
```

And I have a JFrame that is 600 X 600.

```
frame.setSize(600, 600);
frame.setLayout(null);
```

I want to have the bottom of the image touching the bottom of the frame, so I thought this would work:

```
j.setBounds(250, 600 - i.getIconHeight(), i.getIconWidth(), i.getIconHeight());
```

But the image sticks out of the bottom of the frame and not all of it is shown. The bottom of the image is *below* the frame.

EDIT: I need to use absolute positioning for this application (a game).

EDIT2: Here is the code for reference:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private Test() {
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("foo.png");
        JLabel j = new JLabel(i);
        add(j);
        j.setBounds(250, 600 - i.getIconHeight(), i.getIconWidth(), i.getIconHeight());

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: in swing you can use border layout to align objects http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html

Comment: No, I said I need to use absolute positioning because I am making a game and I need to move things freely.

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob, You mean that you're using a null layout manager?

Comment: *"I am using absolute positioning. I need to use this layout, and I cannot use any other layout for what I am doing."*  ***Rubbish!***  Any logic that can be implemented to position elements in a GUI can be wrapped in a custom layout manager.  I also doubt the need for a custom layout at all.  What is the use-case?

Comment: Um... this confuses me. I cannot place an object where ever I want unless I use absolute positioning. Right? err I think so right?

Comment: Layout managers use absolute positioning internally, my comment is about encapsulating logic related to the size and location of the objects it is managing.  BTW - What are the 'objects'?  Images?  In that case I'd create a `gameArena` image and draw every other image (BG, player, enemies, power-ups etc.) to that.  Drop `gameArena` in a label to display it.

Comment: So `gameArena` is a JPanel? If so, how do I... oh I get it. Stick it in the frame and `pack()`. ok :) but how do I set the coordinates of the items within the `gameArena`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

although I would prefer using layout managers for this,just to answer your problem, the parameters of setBounds() are

```
x-coordinate, y-coordinate, width and height
```

You got the idea right that you have to adjust to the frame's size but I think what you need to adjust there is the second parameter which is the y not the height of the Image Icon

Comment: Oh, I though it was setBounds(width, height, x, y); :P

Comment: Well, when I do this the image does not get aligned with the bottom but it sticks out of the frame!

Comment: why do you multiply the iconHeight by 2?

Comment: I don't. ? Where do you see that?

Comment: does your frame have decorations, I mean the bar at the top where the frame title is located?

Comment: by decorations, I mean the frame border :) Try using setUndecorated() on the frame. The frame border is actually also included in the frame size

Comment: I'm guessing the image sticks out because of the extra space designated for the frame border, you may have to consider that for the computation of the y coordinate

Comment: ok I am trying that now... EDIT Ack! It works, but now how do I move my frame?! EDIT2: Well I `setLocationRelativeTo(null)`ed, but now how does the user move it?

Comment: you can add mouselistener on the frame to move it or you can just keep the frame border but just take it into consideration for when setting the y of the image